# React Redux - Mapping over array while rerendering only components holding changed object (in array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Explanation**
Hi, I'm pretty new in 'advanced' React/Redux field. The problem that I have is:
I didn't use actions so the problem and code can be simplified as much as possible.
MyParent component:

```
const MyParent = () => {
  const ref = useRef(0)
  const myArray = useSelector(state => state.someReducer.myArray)

  const changeOneItem = () => {
     dispatch({ type: CHANGE_ONE_ITEM })
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {ref.current ++ }
        <button onClick={() => changeOneItem()}>Add</button>
        {
            myArray.map((item) => 
                <MyChild
                    key={item.id}
                    name={item.text}
                    name2={item.text2}
                ></MyChild>
            )
        }
    </div>
```

Now here is my child component:

```
const MyChild = ({name, name2}) => {
const ref = useRef(0)
return (
    <div>
        <hr/>
        <p>{ref.current ++}</p>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{name2}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

And the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
myArray: [
    {
        id: "1",
        text: "first",
        text2: "001"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        text: "second",
        text2: "002"
    }
]}

case CHANGE_ONE_ITEM:
        return {
            ...state,
            myArray: state.myArray.map(t => t.id == "1" ? {...t, text: "new text"} : t)
        }
```

**Question**
Let's imagine there is ~1,000 objects inside the array. Everytime I change one of the object inside array, parent component rerenders (because of the selector), which also triggers all child components to rerender.
I'm kind of confused when it comes to immutable changes with Redux, when does immutable change helps if this one is not the case?
Every child component has their own key, but still, whole list will get rerender, is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to trigger render on only one child which corresponding object did change?

**Example in main project**
Subtitle translator. You will have table, each row will have own textarea where you can write your subtitle for specific timestamp (start of subtitle - end of subtitle). After leaving the textarea, changes should be saved, that save causes lag because each "child" component (in this case each row) rerenders.

Thanks!
Good luck :)

Comment: What is your yardstick for measuring when the parent and/or children render? Is it the ref mutations? Your render returns should be pure and not have side-effects.

Comment: Yes, I use ref mutations for measuring number of renders. This is just small example code, similar problem I have in main project where I have > 1000 objects in array, and every time my whole list rerenders

Comment: Ok, just know that renders during the "render phase" aren't the same as renders during the "commit phase" when the changes are actually flushed out to the DOM. During each "render phase" render React renders the entire virtual DOM in order to determine the diff and what actually changed. See this [lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/). If you want a more accurate count of renders then update the ref count in a `useEffect` callback which is called once per "commit phase" render.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly do you want to say? The problem is that I 'feel' the lag while using same approach as in this example. Maybe because there is a lot of objects so it's some kind of edge case where I should find workaround. + I added example in my question so it's easier to uderstand.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to say that your contrived code example and way of measuring performance aren't useful. Using an `useEffect` hook allows you to *actually* know when a component renders. There are also dev tools built into the browser to help you hone in on performance issues. You can set the react dev tools to flash the component repaints, and many browsers have performance audits you can run on your code to see memory, cpu, DOM nodes, etc... "performance feels" are one thing, tangible evidence is another.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand, that was my bad that i measured the 'performance' on wrong way. Glad I asked, thanks one more time, I think 'flashing render' in dev tools will help me in my case.
So what abount 'perfomance feel', should I ignore that and try to find workaround for that edge case?

Comment: I wouldn't ignore it. If it feels slow/sluggish then it is definitely worth diving into, you just want to make sure you use the proper tools for the job. What is fast or slow for you may not be for someone else, and what is fast or slow on your machine may not be on a different machine. React is really optimized and runs well out-of-the-box, thousands of nodes. If it's slow it's likely something you've done, so drill down in the performance tab of the dev tools, it will show you how much time is spent on rendering each element in the DOM. If using Chrome, use the LightHouse audits too.

Comment: @KevinBogdan The reason all components will re render DOM is because MyChild will create jsx every time as it's a functional component and since the returned jsx is different `<p>{ref.current ++}</p>` it will update a lot of DOM. You can prevent this by makig MyChild a pure component and not create jsx when props didn't change (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `MyChild` a pure component with React.memo, your reducer already doesn't change all the other elements of the array `t.id == "1" ? {...t, text: "new text"} : t` and each MyChild item has a unuque key so none should re render when you only chanage one item but you have to use React.memo because functional components will **always** re render. That is they will re create jsx but React may not render Dom when current generated jsx is the same as last time.

```js
const { memo, useRef, useCallback, useState } = React;
//using React.memo to make MyChild a pure component
const MyChild = memo(function MyChild({
  id,
  text,
  change,
}) {
  const ref = useRef(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Rendered: {++ref.current} times</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => change(id, e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(() =>
    [...new Array(10)].map((_, i) => ({
      id: i + 1,
      text: `text ${i+1}`,
    }))
  );
  //use callback so change is only created on mount
  const change = useCallback(
    (id, text) =>
      //set data item where id is the id passed to change
      setData((data) =>
        data.map((d) => (d.id === id ? { ...d, text } : d))
      ),
    []//deps array is empty so only created on mount
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <MyChild
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          text={item.text}
          change={change}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This worked! The only difference I made is removing 'change' method and moved spread operator inside reducer (redux). This boosted my performance issue. Thanks!